# Problems binding ng-click with ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to display an input (and hide another) when a link is clicked.

So far I've tried:

```
<input ng-if="form.type=='Other'" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{questions.n3B.placeholder}}" ng-hide="editplaceholder == true"/>
<input ng-show="editplaceholder == true" ng-model="questions.n3B.placeholder" type="text" class="form-control"/>
<a href="" ng-if="form.type=='Other' && editMode" class="edit-link" ng-click="EditPlaceholder()"  >Edit placeholder</a>
```

And the function that gets fired:

```
var EditPlaceholder = function ($scope) {
$scope.editplaceholder = true;
};
```

What am I missing?

I'm kinda new in AngularJS and I think that most of my problems come from lack of a solid foundation on the basics...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add your EditPlaceholder function to the scope in order to call it from ng-click.

Try

```
$scope.EditPlaceholder = function(...){}
```

Comment: Hi Conqueror,

I didn't quiet get the modification you're proposing, I've tried but it doesn't work (and also something doesn't look good).

$scope.EditPlaceholder = function ($scope) {
  $scope.editplaceholder = true;
};

Comment: Once I put it into the right controller, your answer worked perfectly. Thanks!!